# composeWith sub-generator not mocking as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to test my generator, which, using `composeWith()`, relies on the sub-generator [generator-express](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express):

```js
this.composeWith(require.resolve('generator-express/app'), {dirname: this.props.app_name, createDirectory: 'n'});
```

This is an excerpt from my test with the mock dummy generator:

```js
var deps = [
      [helpers.createDummyGenerator(), require.resolve('generator-express/app')]
];

describe('generator-cesium/app Test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        return helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../generators/app'))
            .inDir(path.join(__dirname, 'tmp'))
            .withPrompts({
                viewerContext: '/',  // eslint-disable-line camelcase
                appName: 'app'       // eslint-disable-line camelcase
            })
            .withGenerators(deps)
    });
...
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

```sh
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined)

      at Immediate.setImmediate (node_modules/generator-express/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:406:18)
```

The error, indicating that the sub-generator is still being executed, leads me to believe that the mock is not actually working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the deps array only works for legacy style generators using names alias instead of path names.

Using `require.resolve()`, I think the easiest way to mock a generator would be use a tool like `jest.mock`, `proxyquire` or `mockery`.

For example:

```
jest.mock('../generators/app', () => {
    const helpers = require('yeoman-test');
    helpers.createDummyGenerator();
});
```

Comment: I've had no success using the example method you've shown; my generator test fails with: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'resolved' of undefined` when my generator calls `composeWith(...)`, thereby proving this method still is unable to mock the underlying generator dependency.